# How can I append an item in a random location in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, random, indexing

append will add an item to the end of the list.

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l.append(5)
```

outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

now instead of adding 5 at the end of the list I would like to add it to a random location in the list. let's say 5 is being added to index 2. Number 3 will move one index forward.

```
[1,2,5,3,4]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python | How to append elements to a list randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475518/python-how-to-append-elements-to-a-list-randomly)

Comment: Try `l.insert(your_random_index, your_value)`.

Comment: You *can't* append an item in a random location since by definition to append an item is to place it at the *end*.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `insert` method of list.

```
import random
l = [1,2,3,4]
l.insert(random.randint(0, len(l)), 5)
```

First argument of the method is index, the second argument is value. [See documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert where first argument is index (position), 2nd is value

```
l.insert(2, 5)
```